# unpacking lists inside another list python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume you have a list :

```
mylist=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
```

any pythonic(2.x) way to unpack the inner lists so that new list should look like ?:

```
mylist_n=[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 7):

```
import itertools
mylist=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
print list(itertools.chain(*mylist))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
mylist_n = [j for i in mylist for j in i]
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the last part "**for j in i**" I do not get it, what does this mean?